# Как правильно организовать многопоточность на C#?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, http

Если вам не жалко, можете поделиться исходником, где есть многопоточнось. Смотрел видео видео одного чекера работает в 200-300 потоков спокойно, скорость результата хорошая. Сам тоже написал чекер, если около ста строк, то в 10 потоков работает хорошо, но если же строк около 1к, выводит результат с первых 100-150 строк, дальше данные в лог не записываются, при этом программа продолжает чекать, ресурсы пк потребляет, хоть и мало, и интернет тратит.

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Leaf.xNet;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace mail_cheсk
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            List<string> listSource = new List<string>();
            List<Thread> ListThread = new List<Thread>();
            public static int iPrx = 0;
            bool lifeThread = false;
            //*** Дизайн ***//
            #region
            [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            internal extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint WParam, uint LParam);

            [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            internal extern static bool ReleaseCapture();
            const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
            const uint DOMOVE = 0xF012;
            const uint DOSIZE = 0xF008;

            private void label2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

            private void label2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                label2.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(221, 79, 66);
            }

            private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Close();
            }
            private void label3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                label3.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 1, 248);
            }

            private void label3_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                label3.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }

            private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }

            private void panel3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
            }

            private void panel4_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
            }

            private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
            }
            private void label10_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
            }

            private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (panel5.Visible == false)
                {
                    panel7.Visible = false;
                    panel5.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    panel5.Visible = false;
                }
            }

            private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (panel7.Visible == false)
                {
                    panel5.Visible = false; ;
                    panel7.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    panel7.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            #endregion
            ///*** Работа с файлами ///
            #region
            void Load_proxy()
            {
                using (var open = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    open.Filter = "Proxy (*.txt)|*.txt";
                    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        Data.Proxy_user.Clear();
                        label5.Text = "Добавлено прокси " + File.ReadLines(open.FileName).Count();
                        Data.Proxy_user.AddRange(File.ReadLines(open.FileName));
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void btn_Save_Good_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, Data.Save_good.ToArray());
                }
            }

            private void btn_Save_Bad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void btn_Save_Error_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }
            #endregion

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                btStop.Enabled = false;
            }

            private void btSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    var FileDialog = new OpenFileDialog(); FileDialog.Filter = "Source List (*.txt)|*.txt";
                    if (FileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        listSource.Clear();
                        foreach (var value in File.ReadAllLines(FileDialog.FileName).Distinct())
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            {
                                listSource.Add(value);
                            }
                        }
                        label6.Text = "Добавлено почт " + listSource.Count.ToString();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Add Source File", "Error");
                }
            }
            private void work()
            {
                while (listSource.Count > 0 && lifeThread)
                {
                    string email_user = null;

                    if (listSource.Count > 0)
                    {
                        email_user = listSource[0];
                        listSource.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                    Check(email_user);
                }
            }
            private string Token()
            {
                try
                {
                    string token = null;
                    var request = new HttpRequest();
                    request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
                    HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://www.instagram.com/");
                    token = Regex.Match(response.ToString(), "csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"").Groups[1].Value;
                    return token;
                }
                catch { } return null;
            }
            private void Check(string email_user)
            {
                try
                {
                    string response = "";
                    using (HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest())
                    {
                        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        request.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                        request.AddHeader("X-CSRFToken", Token());
                        request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://www.instagram.com");
                        request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://www.instagram.com/");
                        request.KeepAlive = true;
                        request.UserAgent = Http.RandomUserAgent();
                        RequestParams param = new RequestParams();
                        param["email"] = email_user;
                        response = request.Post("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/attempt/?hl=ru", param).ToString();
                        if (response.Contains(email_user))
                        {
                            lock (this)
                            {
                                string[] names = email_user.Split('@');
                                string name = names[0];

                                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + name + " Не валидный. Поток № " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                    label8.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(label8.Text) + 1);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        if (response.Contains("This field is required"))
                        {
                            lock (this)
                            {
                                string[] names = email_user.Split('@');
                                string name = names[0];
                                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + name + " Валидный. Поток № " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                    label7.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(label7.Text) + 1);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            private void workStart()
            {
                lifeThread = true;
                ListThread.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value); i++)
                {
                    Thread td = new Thread(work);
                    ListThread.Add(td);
                    td.Start();
                }
                btn_Start.Enabled = false;
                btStop.Enabled = true;
            }
            private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (listSource.Count > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(150);
                    workStart();
                }
                else { MessageBox.Show("База email пуста, добавьте почты!"); }
            }
            private void workStop()
            {
                lifeThread = false;
                foreach (Thread thread in ListThread)
                {
                    thread.Abort();
                }
                btStop.Enabled = false;
                btn_Start.Enabled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Работа остановлена");
            }

            private void btStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                workStop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Могу сказать вам только, что вы должны использовать `Task`. Если вы хотите использовать `Task` как `Thread`, используйте `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. Это создаст задачу в новом потоке.

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте `Task` и `async/await`, иначе большинство ваших потоков будут висеть впустую, тратя на пустые циклы ожидания ввода-вывода ядра/потоки процессора, число которых достаточно мало.
А главное - обычные коллекции не потокобезопасны. Используйте вместо `List` что-нибудь из `System.Collections.Concurrent`, например `ConcurrentQueue`. Ну, либо заворачивайте в функции `work` работу со списком в `lock`, если хотите по-старинке всё делать. У вас честно говоря в целом очень не оптимальный код, на `async/await` всё можно написать гораздо проще и понятнее.

Comment: Разобрался, так как блок catch { } ничего не делает это останавливает лог, а вы даже код не почитали и советуете использовать более длинный код, мой же в работе осечек не дает

Comment: @ИванРудаков Послушайте, я много лет пишу промышленный код. Я понимаю, что для вашей задачи совершенно не важно, если ваши потоки несколько раз сделают одну и ту же задачу или наоборот какие-то из задач потеряют в итоге из-за того, что коллекция List не потокобезопасна. Но в реальной разработке так код писать нельзя, и чем раньше вы это поймёте, тем вам же будет лучше. Не хотите учиться - это ваше дело, конечно. Только не удивляйтесь потом, когда будут вылазить странные ошибки на ровном месте из-за того, что вы не понимаете, как это всё реально работает.

Comment: потоки одни и теже данные не используют как что потерь нету. До этого кода я реализововал с ConcurrentDictonary, хоть она и потокобезопасная, но выбивает индекс, что есть ни хорошо.

Comment: @ИванРудаков В функции work вы работаете со списком listSource из разных потоков, не используя блокировку. При этом не просто читаете, а ещё и меняете этот список. При том, что коллекция List не потокобезопасна. Возможно, вам просто везло, не знаю. Что такое " выбивает индекс" я не понимаю, судя по всему вы неправильно работали с ConcurrentDictonary. Потокобезопасность не означает, что там, где вы проверяете Count и там, где удаляете элемент из коллекции эта коллекция не успела измениться.

Comment: так как я не использую блокировку, но я удаляю из  listSource данные, то есть каждый поток берет новые данные, а на запись ставлю лок, чтобы не смешивались данные. Я поэтому и написал может кто то исходник даст как правильно работать с потоками для данной задачи. А про индекс имею ввиду. Данные записываются плохо в коллекцию, если 10 строк  нужно записать, то их может записаться 7... А дальше данные берутся, например берется 10я строка, а в коллекции их 7 и ошибку дает... Мне проще было  исходник разобрать и понять как правильно работать с потоками, так как сам мало в них понимаю.